# node js express routing [Cannot GET: /collection#]

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am a begginer in nodejs. I have a simple api that logs you in with passport, redirects you to /collections. That part works fine, the problem is in POST requests which return

```
    Error: Not Found
   at D:\Movie API\src\server\server.js:44:15
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\Movie API\src\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:82:5)
   at trim_prefix (D:\Movie API\src\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:302:13)
   at D:\Movie API\src\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:270:7
   at Function.proto.process_params (D:\Movie API\src\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:321:12)
   at next (D:\Movie API\src\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:261:10)
   at D:\Movie API\src\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:603:15
   at next (D:\Movie API\src\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:246:14)
   at D:\Movie API\src\server\routes\secure.js:8:11
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\Movie API\src\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:82:5)
   at trim_prefix (D:\Movie API\src\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:302:13)
   at D:\Movie API\src\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:270:7
   at Function.proto.process_params (D:\Movie API\src\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:321:12)
   at next (D:\Movie API\src\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:261:10)
   at Function.proto.handle (D:\Movie API\src\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:166:3)
   at router (D:\Movie API\src\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:35:12)
```

withot Error :

```
Cannot GET /collection
```

I have tried sendig POST requests from postman which gives me an 404.

```
var auth = express.Router();
```

require('./routes/auth.js')(auth, passport);
app.use('/auth', auth);

server routes:

```
var auth = express.Router();
require('./routes/auth.js')(auth, passport);
app.use('/auth', auth);

var secure = express.Router();
require('./routes/secure.js')(secure);
app.use('/', secure);
```

auth path is working fine. It accepst auth file with credentials, and passport whic uses auth credentials. On success it redirects to /collections.
auth:

```
module.exports = function(router, passport){

router.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('index.ejs');
});

router.get('/google', passport.authenticate('google', {scope: ['profile', 'email']}));

router.get('/google/callback', 
  passport.authenticate('google', { successRedirect: '/collections',
                                      failureRedirect: '/' }));


router.get('/logout', function(req, res){
    req.logout();
    res.redirect('/');
})

router.get('/*', function(req, res){
    res.redirect('/auth');
})
};
```

Now this is secure :

```
module.exports = function(router, passport){

router.use(function(req, res, next){
    if(req.isAuthenticated()){
        return next();
    }

    res.redirect('/auth');
})

// Get all collections
router.get('/collections', collection.getAll);

// Create a collection
router.post('/collection', collection.create);
// Get one product, update one product, delete one product
router.route('/collection/:id')
    .get(collection.read)
    .put(collection.update)
    .delete(collection.delete);


}
```

the collection module functions are just responding with a `res.json({id:req.params.id});`

The redirection from /auth to /collections is ok, but on POST /collection I get the mentioned errors. Did anyone have a simillar issue ?

Answer (score 2):

Try `var collection = require('../models/collection');` .. instead of .

This is because the require is the relative path from the file you are in not from root directory.

Answer (score 1):

```
var collection = require('../models/collection');
```

[Source code link](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/blob/069dd07a1732c6a752773aaed9e8c18ab472375f/lib/module.js#L354)

Node.js `require()` uses the CommonJS syntax and all path will be relative to the file where it is being called from.

See the [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html).